# does use database command in mysql lock the whole database?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a serious performance issue about mysql.
The storage engine is myisam.
I find such pattern in slow log:
if the update command is slow, a `use database_name` will be in front of it, and the lock time will be long.

does use database_name command lock the whole database?  will database_name command flush the cache and then has bad effects in update command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the use database command does not have a great cost.

But the UPDATE statement locks the whole table if you use MyISAM.  You're probably seeing multiple UPDATE statements queuing up against each other.

I recommend using InnoDB for all tables.  Not only for its support for row-level locking (actually MVCC which is better than row-level locking), but also InnoDB is superior to MyISAM in terms of resistance against data corruption.

Comment: how can i identify multiple update statements queuing up againt each other. does they have the same  set timestamp=\d+ ?

Comment: Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.  You might see one statement in a state of "Updating" and the others in a state of "Locked".  They will also show a number of seconds each process has been running, and it's likely that they are queued in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

`use database` does *not* lock the database.  It simply provides a default database to reference in future queries.

Answer (score 1):

No the command neither locks the database nor flushes, it simply makes it easier to reference one database when there are many to choose from.  You may want to take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html).

If you are having slow query times, perhaps take a look to see if you are doing any intensive updates to the database as MyISAM does lock the table (rather than the row, like InnoDB) on updates.